# str_detect also finding NA in filter

Tags: r, filter, stringr

I want to filter out rows where a column contains a string. I am using a `tidyverse` solution. The problem I'm having is `str_detect` also seems to be finding `NA` results and so these are also removed by my filter:

```
df1 = data.frame(x1 = c("PI", NA, "Yes", "text"),
                 x2 = as.character(c(NA, 1, NA,"text")),
                 x3 = c("foo", "bar","foo", "bar"))

> df1
    x1   x2  x3
1   PI <NA> foo
2 <NA>    1 bar
3  Yes <NA> foo
4 text text bar

#remove rows which have "PI" in column `x1`:

df2 = df1%>%
  filter(!str_detect(x1, "(?i)pi"))

> df2
    x1   x2  x3
1  Yes <NA> foo
2 text text bar
```

How do I prevent `str_detect` finding `NA`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a condition with `is.na` and `|`.  The `NA` issue is just because for `NA` elements, the `str_detect` returns `NA`, which gets automatically removed by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    filter(is.na(x1) |
       str_detect(x1, regex("pi", ignore_case = TRUE), negate = TRUE))
```

-output

```
   x1   x2  x3
1 <NA>    1 bar
2  Yes <NA> foo
3 text text bar
```

---

i.e. check the output of `str_detect`

```
with(df1, str_detect(x1, regex("pi", ignore_case = TRUE), negate = TRUE))
[1] FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE
```

The `NA` remains as such unless we make it TRUE

```
 with(df1, str_detect(x1, regex("pi", ignore_case = TRUE), negate = TRUE)|is.na(x1))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

Or another option is to `coalesce` with `TRUE` so that all the `NA` elements in `str_detect` will change to `TRUE` value

```
df1 %>% 
   filter(coalesce(str_detect(x1, regex("pi", ignore_case = TRUE), 
       negate = TRUE), TRUE))
    x1   x2  x3
1 <NA>    1 bar
2  Yes <NA> foo
3 text text bar
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try `subset` like below

```
> subset(
+   df1,
+   replace(x1 != "PI", is.na(x1), TRUE)
+ )
    x1   x2  x3
2 <NA>    1 bar
3  Yes <NA> foo
4 text text bar
```